# How to Track UICollectionView index

Tags: ios, swift, variables, uicollectionview

I want a variable in my code that keeps track of the index of my UICollectionView, but I can't get it to work.  After some troubleshooting, I've boiled down the code to the following, which if pasted into an empty viewController should work since no storyboard is involved. The animated gif illustrates the problem. Initially my variable "`selectedItem`" is equal to the UICollectionView Cell text which reflects the `data = [0,1,2,3]`, but then when I swipe right, it immediately becomes off by 1. Then it stays off by 1 until at the last cell where it matches again. The pattern repeats when going in reverse.   Thanks for any help --

[image: ViewController]

```
import UIKit

class CodeCollView2: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  var data = [0,1,2,3] //["0", "1", "2", "3" ]
  let cellId = "cellId2"

  var selectedItem = 0

  lazy var cView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    return cv
  }()

  var indexLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = ""
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
    return label
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupViews()
  }

  func setupViews() {
    cView.register(CCell2.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    view.addSubview(cView)
    cView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    cView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    cView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    cView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    view.addSubview(indexLabel)
    indexLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    indexLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    indexLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CCell2
    selectedItem = indexPath.item
    indexLabel.text = "seletedItem = \(selectedItem)"
    cell.itemValue = data[selectedItem]
    return cell
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return collectionView.frame.size
  }
}

//============== CVCell ==================
class CCell2: UICollectionViewCell {

  var itemValue: Int? {
    didSet {
      if let val = itemValue {
        itemLabel.text = "\(val)"
      }
    }
  }

  var itemLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 100)
    return label
  }()

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = .lightGray
    addSubview(itemLabel)
    itemLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    itemLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    itemLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't rely on `cellForItemAt:` being called in any specific order.  If your collectionView is sized so that it only displays a single item at a time then you can probably user the delegate method `willDisplay:forItemAt:` to track the on-screen item.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but CollectionView is not supposed that smart in that it gives a proposed offset when you scroll. Just using `willDisplay:forItemAt` will not suffice if multiple items can appear on the screen at the same time. You could probably infer the current index from that offset after a scroll has occured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Nikita's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45446633/4691224) mentions, `cellForItemAt` is called when a cell is going to be shown, even if you only see a bit of it and go back to the previous one, so you shouldn't use to decided what cell is at the centre.

`scrollViewDidScroll` is the right way of tracking which cell you have at the centre, and you can print what index you are on with something like this:

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView:UIScrollView)
    {
        let midX:CGFloat = scrollView.bounds.midX
        let midY:CGFloat = scrollView.bounds.midY
        let point:CGPoint = CGPoint(x:midX, y:midY)

        guard

           let indexPath:IndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at:point)

        else
        {
           return
        }

        let currentPage:Int = indexPath.item
        indexLabel.text = "seletedItem = \(currentPage)"
    }
```

Comment: I believe the comments I made for Nikita Gaydukov's solution also apply to your solution since the scrollViewDidScroll fires at every single scroll movement.  That seems to me to be wasteful of the CPU given that I just want to know the index when it stops scrolling. That's why I'm assuming 
 scrollViewDidEndDecelerating  is the better solution. Am I missing something?

Comment: I missed the part that you only want to know what index you are on when it actually ends scrolling, so yes scrollViewDidEndDecelerating will fulfil that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Tracking the selected item in the 'cellForItemAt' is not a good idea. I would suggest you to track it in the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method of the UIScrollViewDelegate. 
Something like this should work:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let currentPage = cView.contentOffset.x / self.view.bounds.width
}
```

Comment: When I used scrollViewDidScroll (as you suggested) including the line that updates the text display ( indexLabel.text = "seletedItem = \(selectedItem)" ), the text displayed wildly as I scrolled from page to page.  This made me conclude that your approach was very "expensive" CPU-wise, even though it did give the correct answer every time the scroll finished.  So instead I tried using scrollViewDidEndDecelerating and when I did I only saw the text display at the end of each scroll. Am I correct in assuming that scrollViewDidEndDecelerating is therefore a better solution?

Comment: @TonyM it is not very CPU expensive. But if you need to know the selected item ONLY after scroll is finished than scrollViewDidEndDecelerating is the way to go. I provided a general solution, that will work in any case (for example if you want to know a 'fraction' of the selected item, for some custom scroll effect or something).